# Other Java Proposals Missing From Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

The "other java proposals" that allows you to use the Ctrl+Space shortcut is missing from my Kempler install.  I have redownloaded and reinstalled fresh from Eclipse and still do not have access to the shortcut from "other java proposals".

When searching here it's been suggested it should be checked in the advanced section of the editor preferences for Java.  I can't find anything about how to enable to disable it here or in the Eclipse help files so I thought I would ask.

Thanks,
Omega

Answer (score 3):

Kepler doesn't have "Other java proposals" but just `Java Proposals`.

This option (or `Java Proposals (Task-Focused)`) is sometimes left unchecked when importing the project to Kepler from a workspace on an older version of eclipse. Hence, your problem might be with workspace than the eclipse dist you are using.

Comment: +1 Hint: If you want to find this in the Eclipse preferences, search for `proposal`. Eclipse will then hide all the preferences entries which aren't matching.

Comment: I have searched through the help, and it actually says that it's still one of the default checked items.  But I have the Java Proposals checked and still get nothing from ctrl+space.  Super frustrating, works fine in Fedora, but on the windows box that I am using to get work done it fails. (Or I fail it?)

Answer (score 0):

I just thought I would "answer" this question incase someone else had the same problem.

It turns out that Synergy+ uses the same keystroke to lock screens.  Even when it's closed, and the service is still running it holds on to key binds.

So, how I fixed it was to go through task manager and kill processes one at a time until I was able to use the shortcut, then went in to Synergy and changed the keybind.